# Push std::array to std::vector with variants

Tags: arrays, vector, variant

How to push the arrays

```
const std::array<int16_t, 3>  arrInt16{-3, 0, 99};
const std::array<uint32_t, 3> arrUint32{3333, 7, 0};
```

into the vector

```
std::vector<std::array<std::Variant<int16_t, uint32_t>, 3>> allArrays;
```

I tried several approaches but all failed. Do I have to insert them element by element?

Some of the apporaches which faild:

```
allArrays.push_back(arrInt16);
allArrays.emplace_back(arrInt16);
allArrays.push_back(arrInt16.data());
allArrays.emplace_back(arrInt16.data());
allArrays.insert(arrInt16);
allArrays.insert(arrInt16.data());
```

Comment: Please show *what*  you tried and *how*  it failed ...